# Ошибка загрузки фейковых данных в Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

начал проект на Symfony 4 и решил не писать данные в базу руками. Поэтому воспользовался примером и скачал 2 пакета

> composer require fzaninotto/faker
>
> composer require cocur/slugify

Ниже прилагаю сам код:
И при попытки сделать

> php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load

вылазит ошибка:

> Cannot autowire service "App\DataFixtures\AppFixtures": argument
> "$slugify" of method    "__construct()" references class
> "Cocur\Slugify\Slugify" but no such service exists.

Подскажите что я делаю не так.

```html
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Faker\Factory;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    private $faker;
    private $slug;

    public function __construct(Slugify $slugify)
    {
        $this->faker = Factory::create();
        $this->slug = $slugify;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->loadPosts($manager);
    }

    public function loadPosts(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
            $posts = new Post();
            $posts->setTitle($this->faker->text(100));
            $posts->setSlug($this->slug->slugify($posts->getTitle()));
            $posts->setBody($this->faker->text(1000));
            $posts->setCreatedAt($this->faker->dateTime);

            $manager->persist($posts);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Решил проблему написав в конструкторе
$this->faker = Factory::create();
        $this->slug = $slugify;

Answer (score 0):

Следуя инструкции на [GitHub](https://github.com/cocur/slugify), активируем пакет:

```
// config/bundles.php
return [
     // ...
     Cocur\Slugify\Bridge\Symfony\CocurSlugifyBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Создаём сервис в config/services.yaml:

```
    App\DataFixtures\AppFixtures:
        $slugify: 'Cocur\Slugify\Slugify'
```

Либо, меняем в конструкторе

```
__construct(Slugify $slugify)
```

на

```
__construct(SlugifyInterface $slugify)
```

Соответственно и

```
use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;
```

на

```
use Cocur\Slugify\SlugifyInterface;
```